# Can I set up a VM Host's drives to appear as if they belong to the VM OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-fusion

A couple things. I added two of the host drives to the shared drives area of the VM. Neither of them show up in the VM's OS.

What I actually would like to do is configure two of these drives that are on the host OS to appear as if they are on the VM. So that I can share them through the VM. Sounds wonkey, I know. The VM is Windows Server 2008 and the Host is Mac OSX Lion. I would like to host my media drives through windows server rather than over OSX as I have nothing but problems.

I'm not sure if this is possible. Any input?

Comment: Have you installed the VMWare Tools in the guest OS?

Comment: actually no. gonna do that right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the [VMWare Tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=340) in order for shared-folders to work (as well as host-guest drag-and-drop and clipboard, graphics drivers, [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Tools#Other_products))

([Specific instructions for VMWare Fusion Tools.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1022048))

Comment: got that taken care of. I have a "network location" in the guest os now that has my shared folders. But I don't have the option to share them. At not through through the context menu

Comment: Try the *Sharing* tab of the folder’s *Properties* dialog. If that doesn’t work; post a screenshot.